# Get last number in string using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following String `"$120 foo $100 bar"` and I want to get just the last number so I end up with just "100".

I've had an attempt at it but can only get the first number (120) instead of the second number. This is what I have so far.

```
price.value.match(/\d+/);
```

Worth noting, on some occasions I may just have one number in the String `"£80 GBP"`. I would like the regex to always give me the last number displayed.

Can anyone suggest the regex I should be using?

Comment: I suggest you experiment on a site such as regex101.com, after reading the documentation and boning up on things like the end-of-string anchor `$`.

Comment: `s.match(/\d+(?!.*\d)/)` should work if you have no line breaks in your strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
\d+(?=\D*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/k0IkVIEL8Z1hFgA0)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last number like so:

```
(\d+)(?=[^\d]+$)
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/K4cf5W/1